# X axis tick labels overlapping x axis when tilted, and overlapping each other when straight (easyggplot2)

Tags: r

I'm trying to make my x axis tick labels not overlap (either with each other or with the x axis).

Here is my simple script (I used it from a tutorial online for easyggplot2)

```
ggplot2.barplot(data=fig1_data, xName='species', yName="total",
            groupName='location', groupColors=c('#0066ff','#cc0000'),
            position=position_dodge(),
            #background and line colors
            backgroundColor="white", color="black", 
            xtitle="Species", ytitle="Total number of beetles caught", 
            mainTitle="Number of beetles caught in ground vs. canopy traps",
            removePanelGrid=TRUE,removePanelBorder=TRUE,
            axisLine=c(0.5, "solid", "black"),
            xtickLabelRotation=30
            )
```

http://tinypic.com/r/rleqsl/9

I'm new to R so explaining in very simple terms would be the most helpful for me. I assume there is a relatively easy fix I just can't seem to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: You will need to add where the `ggplot2.barplot` function comes from and some sample data.

Comment: Have a look here: http://dsgeek.com/2014/09/19/Customizingggplot2charts.html

Comment: While easyggplot2 appears to have an easier interface it lacks some of the customizable functionality of ggplot2. I would recommend you learn to use ggplot2 first, and redo your plot in ggplot2.  I do not see a parameter in ggplot2.barplot that allows you to change the theme element `vjust` that you need to fix your problem.

Comment: You can start with the ggplot2 geom_bar tutorial http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization, and then follow the link above for customizing barplots in ggplot2. @RomanLuštrik ggplot2.barplot is part of the easyGgplot2 package, a wrapper for ggplot2.

Comment: okay great!! I redid it in ggplot2 using geom_bar and was able to fix my problem!! Thank you!